# Threading Volume #9000

Tags: c#, multithreading

Ok, So, I just started screwing around with threading, now it's taking a bit of time to wrap my head around the concepts so i wrote a pretty simple test to see how much faster if faster at all printing out 20000 lines would be (and i figured it would be faster since i have a quad core processor?)

so first i wrote this, (this is how i would normally do the following):

```
System.DateTime startdate = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Producing " + i);
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\tConsuming " + i);
    }

    System.DateTime endtime = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(a.startdate.Second + ":" + a.startdate.Millisecond + " to " + endtime.Second + ":" + endtime.Millisecond);
```

And then with threading:

```
public class Test
{
static ProducerConsumer queue;
public System.DateTime startdate = DateTime.Now;
static void Main()
{
    queue = new ProducerConsumer();
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(ConsumerJob)).Start();


    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Producing {0}", i);
        queue.Produce(i);

    }
    Test a = new Test();
}

static void ConsumerJob()
{
    Test a = new Test();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        object o = queue.Consume();
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\tConsuming {0}", o);

    }
    System.DateTime endtime = DateTime.Now;

    Console.WriteLine(a.startdate.Second + ":" + a.startdate.Millisecond + " to " + endtime.Second + ":" + endtime.Millisecond);
}
}

public class ProducerConsumer
{
readonly object listLock = new object();
Queue queue = new Queue();

public void Produce(object o)
{
    lock (listLock)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(o);        
        Monitor.Pulse(listLock);
    }
}

public object Consume()
{
    lock (listLock)
    {
        while (queue.Count == 0)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(listLock);
        }
        return queue.Dequeue();
    }
}



}
```

Now, For some reason i assumed this would be faster, but after testing it 15 times, the median of the results is ... a few milliseconds different in favor of non threading

Then i figured hey ... maybe i should try it on a million Console.WriteLine's, but the results were similar

am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Um wait a second here. Assume for a second that the console is not serialized. Shouldn't you be dividing the loop into several smaller chunks for a group of threads to process? Right now you are just starting a single thread and delegating all the tasks to it. How can that be faster than processing the tasks on the main thread?

Comment: Yes, i am well aware as this has been pointed out by ShellShock, I've implemented multiple threads now, this didn't increase the performance due to the answer that I've selected's info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing to the console is internally synchronized. It is not parallel. It also causes cross-process communication.

In short: It is the worst possible benchmark I can think of ;-)

Try benchmarking something real, something that you actually would want to speed up. It needs to be CPU bound and not internally synchronized.

Comment: Seems pretty accurate, I've noticed if i minimize the console printing lines it finishes almost immediately

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see you have only got one thread servicing the queue, so why would this be any quicker?

Comment: Gonna vote this up for being true, but i tried adding more threads and it didn't change much

Answer (score 2):

I have an example for why your expectation of a big speedup through multi-threading is wrong:

Assume you want to upload 100 pictures. The single threaded variant loads the first, uploads it, loads the second, uploads it, etc.

The limiting part here is the bandwidth of your internet connection (assuming that every upload uses up all the upload bandwidth you have).

What happens if you create 100 threads to upload 1 picture only? Well, each thread reads its picture (this is the part that speeds things up a little, because reading the pictures is done in parallel instead of one after the other).

As the currently active thread uses 100% of the internet upload bandwidth to upload its picture, no other thread can upload a single byte when it is not active. As the amount of bytes that needs to be transmitted, the time that 100 threads need to upload one picture each is the same time that one thread needs to upload 100 pictures one after the other.

You only get a speedup if uploading pictures was limited to lets say 50% of the available bandwidth. Then, 100 threads would be done in 50% of the time it would take one thread to upload 100 pictures.

Answer (score 1):

"For some reason i assumed this would be faster"

If you don't know why you assumed it would be faster, why are you surprised that it's not? Simply starting up new threads is never guaranteed to make any operation run faster. There has to be some inefficiency in the original algorithm that a new thread can reduce (and that is sufficient to overcome the extra overhead of creating the thread).

Answer (score 1):

All the advice given by others is good advice, especially the mention of the fact that the console is serialized, as well as the fact that adding threads does not guarantee speedup.

What I want to point out and what it seems the others missed is that in your original scenario you are printing everything in the main thread, while in the second scenario you are **merely delegating the entire printing task to the secondary worker**. This cannot be any faster than your original scenario because **you simply traded one worker for another**.

A scenario where you might see speedup is this one:

```
for(int i = 0; i < largeNumber; i++)
{
    // embarrassingly parallel task that takes some time to process
}
```

and then replacing that with:

```
int i = 0;
Parallel.For(i, largeNumber,
    o =>
    {
       // embarrassingly parallel task that takes some time to process
    });
```

This will split the loop among the workers such that each worker processes a smaller chunk of the original data. If the task does not need synchronization you should see the expected speedup.

Comment: +1 for a code implementation of getting multiple threads running at once, I already figured it out using Google, but the way i did it is not quite like this

Answer (score 0):

Cool test.

One thing to have in mind when dealing with threads is *bottlenecks*. Consider this:

> You have a Restaurant. Your kitchen can make a new order every 10
>   minutes (your chef has a bladder problem so he's always in the
>   bathroom, but is your girlfriend's cousin), so he produces 6 orders an
>   hour.
>
> You currently employ only one waiter, which can attend tables
>   immediately (he's probably on E, but you don't care as long as the
>   service is good).
>
> During the first week of business everything is fine: you get
>   customers every ten minutes. Customers still wait for exactly ten
>   minutes for their meal, but that's fine.
>
> However, after that week, you are getting as much as 2 costumers every
>   ten minutes, and they have to wait as much as 20 minutes to get their
>   meal. They start complaining and making noises. And god, you have
>   noise. So what do you do?
>
> Waiters are cheap, so you hire two more. Will the wait time change?
>   Not at all... waiters will get the order faster, sure (attend two
>   customers in parallel), but still some customers wait 20 minutes for
>   the chef to complete their orders.You need another chef, but as you
>   search, you discover they are lacking! Every one of them is on TV
>   doing some crazy reality show (except for your girlfriend's cousin who
>   actually, you discover, is a former drug dealer).

In your case, waiters are the threads making calls to Console.WriteLine; But your chef is the Console itself. It can only service so much calls a second. Adding some threads might make things a bit faster, but the gains should be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple sources, but only 1 output.  It that case multi-threading will not speed it up.  It's like having a road where 4 lanes that merge into 1 lane.  Having 4 lanes will move traffic faster, but at the end it will slow back down when it merges into 1 lane.